# Google Drive api Permission value field required

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer, google-api-js-client

I am writing an angular code to give permission to another account to access a particular file in google drive.

```
public async givepremission(fileid,email){
  await gapi.client.setApiKey(this.credconst.APIkey.toString());

  return await gapi.client.load("drive","v3")
 .then(async () => 
 {
    return await gapi.client.drive.permissions.create({
   "fileId": fileid,
   "resource": {
     "role": "reader",
     "type": "user",
     "emailAddress": email
   }
 }) },
       (err) => { 
         this.toastr.error('Google API error');
         throw(err);
       });
 

}
```

But all i am getting is an error

```
domain: "global"
reason: "required"
message: "Permission value field required"
locationType: "other"
location: "permission.value"
```

I tried it in the https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create **Try This API** there it is working fine but in my project it throws the above error.
The account I am using to give permission is not a G-Suite user.
I have no idea why this error pops up?

How can I solve this issue?

-Thanks

Comment: Try removing the quotes `"` around the key values

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Thanks for the reply. I removed the quotes `"` it still looks the same.

Comment: Can you log your email and fileid values before you send the request? Also, what version of Drive are you using?

Comment: The version of drive i am using is V3 . And the email id and the file id values are the same that i used in the Try This API. I tried it by passing the fileid and email id manually also. still did not work. Thanks for your response @RafaGuillermo

Answer (score 1):

if you have a look here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert
under "Optional Properties" you have the value field
here's the requestBody you should pass:

```
requestBody:{
                emailAddress:'fabrizio@keyko.io',
                role:'writer',
                type:'user',
                value: 'fabrizio@keyko.io'
            },
```

I had the same error but now it works for me.